# Send username to aws Lambda function triggered by aws Cognito user confirm

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am trying to write a Lambda function that makes a folder in an s3 bucket named after a newly confirmed cognito user. This will allow me to keep that user's access limited to their folder. I have created a Lambda function that can create a folder in s3 using a username passed through Lambda's test event object. I know cognito has a "confirmation event" trigger, and I have selected my function to run on that trigger, but I do not know how to retrieve the username from that event. Screenshot below is of my Lambda code.
[my lambda function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqP2L.png).

Let me know if I need to provide more information. I've seen stuff about possibly using amazon's API gateway but in the hour and a half or so that I've messed with API gateway I haven't come any closer to figuring out how to solve this problem.

Thanks!
~Ben

Comment: Please disregard my dumb console logs. They were from a different bug that I already solved.

Answer (score 11):

Good question, at documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-lambda-trigger-syntax-post-confirmation.html) they say only about `request.userAttributes` which obviously doesn't contain username.

As I checked, whole event object for post-confirmation trigger looks like this:

```
{
    "version": "1",
    "region": "eu-central-1",
    "userPoolId": "eu-central-1_45YtlkflA",
    "userName": "user4",
    "callerContext": {
        "awsSdkVersion": "aws-sdk-java-console",
        "clientId": "4736lckau64in48dku3rta0eqa"
    },
    "triggerSource": "PostConfirmation_ConfirmSignUp",
    "request": {
        "userAttributes": {
            "sub": "a2c21839-f9fc-49e3-be9a-16f5823d6705",
            "cognito:user_status": "CONFIRMED",
            "email_verified": "true",
            "email": "asdfsdfsgdfg@carbtc.net"
        }
    },
    "response": {}
}
```

So basically, just `event.userName` will retrieve username.

**UPDATE**

Recent documentation:

- [User Pool Lambda Trigger Event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html#cognito-user-pools-lambda-trigger-event-parameter-shared)
- [Post Confirmation Lambda Trigger Parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-post-confirmation.html#cognito-user-pools-lambda-trigger-syntax-post-confirmation)

Comment: They also didn't mention about username at [cognito triggers common parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-lambda-trigger-syntax-shared.html)

Comment: `sub` is cognito user id ?

Comment: no, sub is different. it's some form of internalish unique id.